# Run Length Encoding (RLE) and Move To Front (MTF) in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression

I have made two quite basic algorithms used for lossless data compression.

This is my RLE:

```
#include <string>

std::string rle(const std::string& input) // encode (aaaaeecd -> 4a2e1c1d)
{
    std::string output;

    int n = input.size();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n)
    {
        int run_count = 1;
        int max_run_count = std::min(255, n - i); // condition: i + run_count < n, runcount <= 255
        while(run_count < max_run_count && input[i + run_count] == input[i])
            run_count++;
        output += run_count; // run_count is between 0 and 255 (unsigned char)
        output += input[i];
        i += run_count;
    }

    return output;
}

std::string irle(const std::string& input) // decode (4a2e1c1d -> aaaaeecd)
{
    std::string output;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i += 2)
    {
        int nb = (int)(unsigned char)input[i]; // range between 0 and 255
        for(int k = 0; k < nb; k++)
            output += input[i+1];
    }

    return output;
}
```

and here goes my MTF:

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

/*
if alphabet A = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    then string "accbc" is encoded 02021
    (a is at index 0, alphabet remains {'a', 'b', 'c'}, outputs 0 ;
     c is at index 2, alphabet becomes {'c', 'a', 'b'}, outputs 2 ;
     c is at index 0, alphabet remains {'c', 'a', 'b'}, outputs 0 ;
     b is at index 2, alphabet becomes {'b', 'c', 'a'}, outputs 2 ;
     a is at index 1, alphabet becomes {'a', 'b', 'c'}, outputs 1)
*/
std::string mtf(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;

    std::list<char> alphabet; // constant erase/insert
    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        alphabet.push_back((char)i);

    for(char c: input)
    {
        auto c_it = find(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), c); // find char c in the alphabet
        output += distance(alphabet.begin(), c_it); // output index of char c in the alphabet
        // move character to the front of the alphabet
        alphabet.erase(c_it);
        alphabet.insert(alphabet.begin(), c);
    }

    return output;
}

/*
reverse operation:
    for each number, outputs the character at the corresponding index in the alphabet
        then move this character to the front of the alphabet
        and keep going
*/
std::string imtf(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;

    std::deque<char> alphabet; // constant erase (begin) & operator[] ; insert (middle) is O(n)
    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        alphabet.push_back((char)i);

    for(unsigned char n: input)
    {
        char temp_c = alphabet[n];
        output += temp_c;
        alphabet.erase(alphabet.begin() + n);
        alphabet.insert(alphabet.begin(), temp_c);
    }

    return output;
}
```

I know there are many possible improvments possible, especially for the RLE algorithm. I would just like a review on the C++ syntax I've used, especially on the structures I have chosen.

Answer (score 4):

Looks quite nice, but let's get down to ripping it apart.

First your runlength-encoding:

1. Try to use the same type for size-variables / indices throughout:
   `std::basic_string<...>` uses `std::size_t`.
   That way you would also heal the one sign-mismatch.
2. Your comment about the encoded form `// encode (aaaaeecd -> 4a2e1c1d)` is wrong.
   You probably meant: `// encode (aaaaeecd -> \x04a\x02e\x01c\x01d)`
3. You are wasting `\x00` and thus the chance to encode runs of length 256.
   (Yes, the comment `// run_count is between 0 and 255 (unsigned char)` is wrong.)
4. You are missing the header `<algorithm>`.

Next your Move-To-Front:

1. I suggest you move from `std::list` to `std::array`.
   A list is a far too heavy data-structure, jumping every-which-way in memory kills your performance quite easily.
2. The `std::deque` is a bit better, but using a `std::array` would probably still handily beat it due to simplicity.